# Create Windows/Macintosh Projector from Flash Builder 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

Am I able to publish a Windows/Macintosh projector from Flash Builder 4? I would like a solution that stays within the IDE, rather than having to open FlashPlayer.exe and export the EXE/App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing this question...doesn't seem possible. I'm sticking with Flash CS5 to publish projectors.

Comment: I just tested this and Flash Player 10 standalone DOES work to export projectors. 11 for some reason did not.

Answer (score 6):

You can display your swf in the standalone flash player, and then create the projector from there (file -> create projector).

http://download.macromedia.com/pub/flashplayer/updaters/10/flashplayer_10_sa.exe

Answer (score 1):

I've had to do this with FB As3 projects. You have to convert your project type to Flash Professional Project: right-click project in the Package Explorer / Add/Change Project Type / Add Flash Professional Project Type. You'll have to create a fla to use as the source. Set the fla Class in the Properties panel to the main class of your project, and add all your resource libs & SWCs to Flash Professional Project: File/ActionScript Settings/Library path tab. This is important or you'll get compile errors. Seems like FB should do this for you, but it doesn't. Now in Flash professional: Commands/Export as Projector.

Many Years too late, but for future reference.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not even a Flash dev anymore. Thanks for answering, though! Hope it helps someone.