# How to create a Windows projector .exe from a Flex application using a Mac

Tags: windows, macos, apache-flex, flash, projector

I have a flex application (.swf) and want to create a projector file. When I choose File-> create projector I get the .app file because I work on a Mac. I know I can create both projector formats for windows and mac using the export feature in Flash Professional. But this is not an option since it's Flex.

Is there any other way rather than switching to windows to create the file?

Answer (score 0):

Flex doesn't have any sort of projectors support as far as I know.  What it does have is Adobe AIR support and you can use Captive Runtime to create an exe.

I'm pretty sure you can only do this inside a Windows OS; so to create an AIR Captive Runtime exe on a Mac, you'll need to run Windows in visualization.

Comment: It is possible to create a projector directly from a flex swf without AIR but only targeted for the OS you are running. With FLA there is no problem because you can create projectors for both OS. IMO adobe missed to add this feature to Flash Builder.

Comment: @dominik How?  What tool are you using to create the projector?  A command line tool?  Or what menu option are you using from Flash Builder?  Also see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496274/create-windows-macintosh-projector-from-flash-builder-4

Comment: I open the swf and choose File->Create Projector from the FlashPlayer menu. When I do that with OSX it generates MyFlexApp.app... Doing so with Windows the result would be MyFlexApp.exe.. But there is no possibility to create both with each OS

Comment: So, you're using the stand alone Flash Player to do this?  It sounds like a limitation of the stand alone player, which is completely unrelated to Flex.  I can accept that it does suck, though.

Comment: Exactly, I use the stand alone player. Seems that I have to use a virtual windows installation to get my .exe.. That's annoying

Comment: So using the "Export Release Build" Menu on Flash Builder 4.5, I can select "Signed native installer". But this gives me (running os x) only a DMG. Do I really have to have Windows, just to export an exe. In the Flash IDE, it's no problem.